# Sitecore 8:Patching an agent

Tags: sitecore, config, patch

I need to patch agent in other environment so I have created a patch as below:

```
 <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent">
  <patch:attribute name="interval" value="01:00:00" />
  <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">smart</param>
  <param desc="languages">en</param>
</agent>
```

Here I patch attribute using `<patch:attribute name="interval" value="01:00:00" />`

But how can I patch a param?.Also how can I test the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch exactly as you have posted, i.e. if the param matches an existing param of the same name then it will overwrite it. There is no need for any additional patch: attributes.

You can check the final config from `http://<mysite>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to patch `param`, use `patch:instead`:

```
<param desc="languages" patch:instead="param[@desc='languages']">en|pl</param>
```

You can test the patched values by accessing `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` url on your server