# Patching web.config in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, config, patch

I have a need to add an additional line to the cleanupagent section in our web.config in sitecore.
I would like to add the following line:

```
<remove folder="/App_Data/MediaCache" pattern="*.json" maxAge="01.00:00:00" recursive="true">
```

Here is the config xml.

```
<sitecore>
  <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent">
    <files hint="raw:AddCommand">
      <remove folder="/App_Data/MediaCache" pattern="*.json" maxAge="01.00:00:00" recursive="true" patch:after="files[@hint='raw:AddCommand']"/>
    </files>
  </agent> 
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sitecore 8:Patching an agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110980/sitecore-8patching-an-agent)

Comment: This post describes how to modify an existing entry.  In my case, I need to add an entry before a similar entry.  There are posts on how to do this but they are not working for me.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: No worries, thought it might be the same issue... looks like @jammykam has you covered!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that Sitecore is matching to an existing node, the existing `folder="/App_Data/MediaCache"` element, and replacing that based on it's node matching rules instead of inserting a new one.

In order to prevent it from matching, you need to make your node more unique, the simplest way is to add an additional attribute, e.g. `desc="json"` (you can also use `name` or `hint` attributes instead):

```xml
<sitecore>
  <scheduling>
    <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent">
      <files>
        <remove folder="/App_Data/MediaCache" pattern="*.json" maxAge="01.00:00:00" recursive="true" desc="json" />
      </files>
    </agent>
  </scheduling>
</sitecore>
```

The patch should insert a new element in config now instead of replacing.